# Why does my local SQL Express have to allow remote connections to use a local MDF?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection-string

When I set up my VB.net program to read from a local MDF database file (SQL), it tells me that I need remote connections.  Details follow:

I have a Visual Studio `vb.net` application.   It needs a database, so I downloaded SQL Express and ran a script to add my database.   This worked fine.    Then I wanted to send my program to a colleague, and I thought I should copy the database MDF and LDF files to the App_Data folder of the program, and then use a connection string that can read the MDF.

The connection string seems to be OK:

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\gideonwroteprograms\EchoTheory\Echo
Theory\bin\Debug\App_Data\EchoDatabase.mdf;Database=EchoDatabase;Trusted_Co
nnection=Yes;
```

but I get a message saying I now need to allow remote connections (which I regard as a security risk).
The message is:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while 
establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was 
not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL 
Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network 
Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
```

Comment: The error only says that it can't connect to SQL Server. That means `.\SQLEXPRESS` is unreachable (which typically means it's not running, which typically means it's not installed). Did your colleague *also* download SQL Express?

Comment: That error message is generic. If you're not trying to connect to that instance from a remote client then you don;t need remote connections enabled.

Comment: SQL Express must be installed on your colleague's machine.